# How to write new shapefiles from exisiting GPS coordinates in R?

Tags: r, gps

I am a novice with R maps and I would like to graphically display plant species distributions as polygons on a map. I have a csv file of UTM coordinates. I am using the maps and maptools programs in R and I have been able to read in existing ESRI shapefiles. The discussion posts that I have seen all seem to deal with reading in existing shapefiles and editing them somewhat and "rewriting" them back out. Is there a simple way to convert my csv file into a shapefile for mapping purposes? Thank you for your help, Eric

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you provide at least a representative sample of your data, show what you have already tried, and show why/how it didn't work.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "polygons on a map"? If you have UTM coordinates you could plot them as points.

Answer (score 1):

You should have more info about your coordinate reference system. And I'm not sure about what you mean with 'polygon' : i think that .csv can only contain coordinates points.

Here is an exemple of workflow : create a simple data.frame; set coordinates ; write shapefile ; read shapefile back; and plot simple map. Hope it helps. Instead of creating a data.frame, you could juste import your .csv.

```
# Load libraries
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
# set CRS . For epsg code, see http://spatialreference.org/
projTest<-CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
# create a temp dir for shapefiles
trashMap<-tempdir()
# create dumb data:
occData<-data.frame(x=c(12,13,14,20),y=c(0,1,4,9),obs=c("a","b","c","d"))
# set x and y as coordinates
coordinates(occData)<-c('x','y')
# assign CRS
proj4string(occData)<-projTest
# write simple shapefile in trashMap dir
writeOGR(occData, trashMap, layer='testLayer', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
# get list of Layers
layers<-ogrListLayers(trashMap)
# read shapefile and selected layer
occData2<-readOGR(trashMap, layers)
# Modify data 
occData2$newColumn<-c('no','stress','','dude')
occData2
# verify that is projected
is.projected(occData2)
# display projection type
proj4string(occData2)
# print maps before and after export in shapefile.
print(spplot(occData, auto.key=F, col.regions='black', scales=list(draw=T), pch=2, cex=1))
print(spplot(occData2, auto.key=F, col.regions='black', scales=list(draw=T), pch=2, cex=1))
```